# programmatically moveTo selectToUISlider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am able to change the content of a gallery when selecting the date from a slider. Dynamically, it works no problem, but after, if there's no image in selecting the date I use ajax to get values from last uploading of images of the date. My aim is when user selects the date from slider if there's no slider to move 
to last uploading of the image date.

I am not able to this.

```
enter coif(ajaxCevap != "" && ajaxCevap != null ){
                    var ajaxCevapDizi = ajaxCevap.split("/");
                    var ensonyil = ajaxCevapDizi[0]; 
                    var ensonay = ajaxCevapDizi[1]; 
                    var ensongun = ajaxCevapDizi[2]; 
                    /*
                    alert("ensonyil " + ensonyil + " ensonay " + ensonay + " ensongun " + ensongun)
                    */

                    var ensonyilSlider = $('select#yil').selectToUISlider().next();
                    ensonyilSlider.slider('option', 'value', ensonyil); 

                    var ensonaySlider = $('select#ay').selectToUISlider().next();
                    ensonaySlider.slider('option', 'value', ensonay); 

                    var ensongunSlider = $('select#gun').selectToUISlider().next();

                    ensongunSlider.slider('moveTo', ensongun);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is pretty old, but I just had to solve this as well.
I am using this plugin to show change over time.

You need to set the value of the `select` element to what you want, then `trigger` the `change` event to get the plugin to react.

`$('select#timeline').val('2018:Q4').trigger('change');`